# Is there a way to calculate SEAc specifically using the maxLikOverlap Function in SIBER package?

Tags: r, overlap, jquery-isotope

I am attempting to calculate the % overlap between the SEAc ellipses of 2 groups (group 7 & group 8) in community #4 using stable isotope data and the SIBER R package. I have followed the vignette example "Ellipse Overlap" that comes in the SIBER package and used the following code:

```
> head(data.sb)
         iso1     iso2 group community
1  0.09881122 3.807466    10         4
2 -0.16367095 3.775113     8         4
3 -0.24213029 3.845701     8         4
4 -0.22786495 3.813348     8         4
5 -0.24213029 3.845701     8         4
6 -0.22786495 3.813348     8         4

siber.sb=createSiberObject(data.sb)

ellipse1 = "4.7"
ellipse2 = "4.8"

sea.overlap <- maxLikOverlap(ellipse1, ellipse2, siber, 
                             p.interval = NULL, n = 100)
sea.overlap
```

My output is:

```
> sea.overlap 
      area.1       area.2      overlap 
1.727520e-01 5.213493e-02 2.032879e-20
```

The code is working however, from my understanding this is calculating the overlap of the SEA ellipses and not the SEAc (small sample size corrected) ellipses. There doesn't seem to be any information on how to calculate overlap using SEAc anywhere.

How to calculate % SEAc overlap?

Answer (score 1):

I am no expert at all but during my current work I have found that when you change the n = 100 into n=1000 in the maxLikOverlap() function (so you create a more accurate mean area by increasing the iterations),
the areas are practically the same as the SEAc areas calculated with groupMetricsML(). At least that's how it is with my data.

and this is how you can calculate the proportion of the overlap compared to the non-overlapping area of both niches:

```
 SEAc.overlap <- maxLikOverlap( "community.group", "community.group", your.data, p.interval = NULL, n = 1000)

 niches.Xover <- SEAc.overlap[3] / (SEAc.overlap[2] + SEAc.overlap[1] - SEAc.overlap[3]
```

in general i can recommend  [this website](https://sites.google.com/view/brianhayden/home?authuser=0) very much as a help in stable isotope analysis!